# Adding pdflatex and lualatex gnuplot graphing capabilities

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex, graphs, gnuplot

I am using Windows 10 and TeXstudio (latest version) as TeX editor and TeXLive (if matters). In chapter 22.6 page 345 of tikz manual, version 3.1.9a is suggested for more powerful graphing engine to be used with pdflatex the external (for LaTeX) application `gnuplot`. I tried but with no success to integrate this program in pdflatex. What I want is to work in pdflatex or lualatex and call gnuplot when necessary to graph a plot inside pdflatex or lualatex (and not to include gnuplot graphics as external images in pdflatex or lualatex).
I found and downloaded the version 5.5 (I think is the latest) of gnuplot, which does not require a setup procedure (no installation). Just download the zipped folder, unzip it and place the contents directly in C drive. Taking some help from internet, I was suggested to pass the option `pdflatex--shell-escape` in  `options->configure texstudio->Build->User Commands` and the option `--enable-write18` in `options->configure texstudio->Commands->PdfLaTeX` as you can see in the pictures, but with no success. Now I am facing a standoff, not knowing what else I have to do. Here I need your help: What more I have to do or what I have to change? Is there a way to do so using command prompt of Windows 10? I looked up on the internet for help, but most of these pages refer to older versions of gnuplot with the installation procedure and use a very important step through this procedure.
[image: options->configure texstudio->Build->User Commands]
[image: options->configure texstudio->Commands->PdfLaTeX]

I am also trying to compile this small code but what I get is the text part of the file and no graph in the output file without any errors. On the other hand if I paste the graph part of this code in the gnuplot command I get the graph. So pdflatex cannot call gnuplot to plot the graph. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{gnuplottex}            
\author{Miltos P.}  
\title{Gnuplot Integration into \LaTeX}\date{\today}  
\begin{document}\maketitle\vskip-15pt\hrule\vskip15pt  
    \begin{gnuplot}  
        set title '\textbf{Gnuplot Testing}'  
        set ylabel '$\eta$'  
        set xlabel '\% wt.'  
        set xrange [0:10]  
        set xtics 0,1,10  
        set ytics 0,20,100  
        unset key  
        plot x*x  
    \end{gnuplot}  
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18` are the same thing. But beside this: setting up your editor should be the last step. First try to run gnuplot in a command line to be sure that it works. Then try to compile a tex document in the command.

Comment: I can run gnuplot and plot some simple functions as sin(x), (x*x)-x. But I can't open any tex file with gnuplot command. I get an error:  "eg1.tex" line 1: invalid command. How can I fix it, tried some terminals cairolatex, pslatex but with no success. What I have to do?

Comment: I have no idea, I never used gnuplot. But if you want help you will have to be more specific and not speak vagely of "any tex file".

Comment: I added a specific .tex file that cannot make it work. Hope this will help anyone knows better than me to help me.

Comment: As above, what command line have you used? I have long stopped using Texstudio, but it will be your setup - e.g why is there no space after pdflatex and why are you calling shell-escape twice (you don't need a user command if you main command does this already)

Comment: @Aubrey Blumsohn I have deleted the user command, so the space error is eliminated. Now I have only the main command. What do you mean by what command line I have used, I didn't understand this question, what am I missing here? Do you mean the command line of wgnuplot.exe or the cmd line of Windows?

Comment: Now I am getting this message: (still no graph)
`'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
system returned with code 1 system returned with code 1 system returned with code 1
Process exited normally`

Comment: try with `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}`. The code seems to use that as a synonym for windows.

Comment: Although I have texlive distribution it worked! And also needed to add the option `[terminal=pdf]` next to `\begin{gnuplot}`. Ulrike, better than perfect for someone who never used gnuplot! I am amazed!